# what is causing the server to go down?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 server Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS and every week it keeps shutting down for whatever reason I have no idea. I go in the aws console and reboot the server and all is well. What can be causing this. I can ssh in and I want to know if anyone knows of where to look and what to look for. Is there a file or an error log that will tell me what is causing the server to shut down...any ideas..

Here is the [domain](http://ec2-50-16-142-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) if that helps

Comment: Shuts down at the same time every time, or at random?

Comment: random// i wish i knew when

Comment: Could it be memory and if so how do i check

Comment: Isn't that a virtual cloud server? If it is a hardware problem I don't think you can check without contacting Amazon and having them look at the issue. Checking memory via software isn't extremely reliable, and I don't know how you could trust any hardware diags that are being abstracted through virtualization to diagnose the physical host.

Comment: Plus having the VM moved to another host, which should be invisible to you (I'd think, I don't use Amazon's service) would make the problem magically disappear for you unless the VM stays "sticky" to a particular host. Again, don't know how it's implemented on their side.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through the system logs, they're located in /var/log - the main one is `messages`

Comment: can it be memory...any idea how to verify

Comment: memory corruption on an EC2 instance would bring the whole server down, not just you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're running an EC2 instance. There won't be any kind of hardware cause for this. (I'm not saying it's impossible, it's just highly unlikely).

Next, take a look in `/var/log/kern.log`. Lines here are prefixed with the number of second since the machine booted, so scroll back up to point `[0000000.00]`. Anything in the logfile before that are the last kernel messages logged before the machine shutdown. That might give you some clues as to what happened (Edit your original question and post in any suspicious lines, if you find any.)